# How fast is glDispatchCompute?

Tags: opengl, compute-shader

[Official OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_Shader) says

> Compute shaders are not part of the regular rendering pipeline. So when executing a Drawing Command, the compute shader linked into the current program or pipeline is not involved.

So I expect it to invoke faster than `glDrawArrays`. Can anyone provide more details about the overhead?

Is `glDispatchComputeIndirect​` the faster alternative because it skips error-checks?

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone provide more details about the overhead?

glDrawArrays overhead is small when you draw enough primitives for each call to it, this is true for all drawing commands: less draw calls = more performance.

> Is glDispatchComputeIndirect​ the faster alternative because it skips error-checks?

No, as Nicol Bolas said, you don't usually use a compute shader when you need a vertex-fragment shader, although there are situation whens this is not so clear.

glDrawArraysIndirect exists. This function is similar to glDrawArrays but takes the rendering command information from a buffer on the GPU. This is very useful if the rendering command information is generated on the GPU, to avoid reading it (avoiding expensive GPU to CPU copy). However, this is a special case.

glDrawArrays overhead will be big when you call it with a low primitive count. Avoid this situation by grouping multiple objects and meshes. glMultiDrawArrays  can be useful​ then: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Multi-Draw

Answer (score 0):

The question is essentially irrelevant.

Compute shaders are for computing data. The rendering pipeline is for rendering stuff. You don't use one for a task where you need the other.

If you're trying to build indirect rendering commands, why would you go through the effort of making such computations look like a drawing operation instead of just making a simple CS? And if you're trying to actually draw stuff, a compute operation wouldn't have access to most of the stuff that makes rendering fast in 90% of cases.

So it doesn't matter if one is faster or slower than the other, because you wouldn't use one for the same tasks as the other. And since they do two completely different things, there's no way to gauge the performance of one relative to the other.

It's like asking whether `sin` is faster than `sqrt`. It doesn't really matter, because you cannot replace one with the other. If you need a `sin`, `sqrt` isn't going to help. And vice-versa.

> it skips error-checks?

Who says it "skips error-checks"?

Dispatch operations still have to make sure that any textures/images/buffers which the CS needs are actually bound and are appropriate for the CS.

Comment: So according to you it is not allowed for me to ask about the overhead of that command? You CAN replace one with the other. This is what people have been doing before the introduction of CS. "...however, indirect dispatch bypasses OpenGL's usual error checking." (This is from the link I provided). Perhaps you should read the question of this thread again.

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan: "*This is from the link I provided*" I know; **I wrote** that Wiki article. And you should note that the quote in question is talking about how glComputeDispatch **Indirect** behaves differently from the non-indirect version. That is, it bypasses OpenGL's normal error mechanisms in so far as the number of workgroups being dispatched is concerned. Hence the part where I say, "As such, attempting to dispatch with out-of-bounds work group sizes can cause a crash or even a GPU hard-lock, so be careful when generating this data."

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan: "*You CAN replace one with the other. This is what people have been doing before the introduction of CS.*" People have been building *hacks* to allow them to make a rendering process compute arbitrary values. And I have yet to see anyone replace a genuine rendering command (aka: drawing triangles) with a compute shader. My point is that you use the most appropriate tool for the task at hand. If you need to compute arbitrary stuff, you use a CS. If you need to render, you use the rendering pipeline.